# Citing a book chapter

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, output

I'm trying to cite some chapters in a book in a `.bib` file however when I compile the `.tex` file, I got some of the chapters without the authors names. I don't know the reason and how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
  @inbook{bitam2014bio1,
  title={Bio-inspired Routing Protocols for Vehicular Ad-Hoc Networks},
  author={Bitam, Salim and Mellouk, Abdelhamid},
  chapter = {Vehicular Ad Hoc Networks},
  year={2014},
  publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
  }

  @inbook{bitam2014bio2,
  title={Bio-inspired Routing Protocols for Vehicular Ad-Hoc Networks},
  author={Bitam, Salim and Mellouk, Abdelhamid},
  chapter = {Routing for Vehicular Ad Hoc Networks},
  year={2014},
  publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
  }

  @inbook{bitam2014bio3,
  title={Bio-inspired Routing Protocols for Vehicular Ad-Hoc Networks},
  author={Bitam, Salim and Mellouk, Abdelhamid},
  chapter = {Conventional Routing Protocols for VANETs},
  year={2014},
  publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
  }

  @inbook{bitam2014bio4,
  title={Bio-inspired Routing Protocols for Vehicular Ad-Hoc Networks},
  author={Bitam, Salim and Mellouk, Abdelhamid},
  chapter = {Bio-inspired Routing Protocols for VANETs},
  year={2014},
  publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
  }
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: What do you mean "without the author name"? You obviously use a bibstyle which suppresses the author (and uses a line).

Comment: @TeXnician In the output, [12]  doesn't have the authors names like [11]. I'm using `ieee` style.

Comment: Yeah and obviously this suppresses the repetition of authors. That's a style decision!

Comment: If the OP uses `biblatex` as tagged (the `biblatex-ieee`) style, they will need the option `dashed=false`.

Comment: @moewe man it worked!! Thanks a lot. I suggest you to post this as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be mis-using the `chapter` field. I suggest you rename the `chapter` field to `title`, change `title` to `booktitle`, provide numbers in the `chapter` field, and also provide `pages` fields.

As @moewe has pointed out in a comment, it actually makes little sense to provide separate entries for each of the book's four chapters. You may want to provide a single entry for entire book and be more specific as to which chapter you're citing in the citation call-outs.

A full MWE that keeps the four separate entries (one for each chapter):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@inbook{bitam2014bio1,
  title        = "Vehicular Ad~Hoc Networks",
  booktitle    = "Bio-inspired Routing Protocols for Vehicular Ad-Hoc Networks",
  author       = "Bitam, Salim and Mellouk, Abdelhamid",
  chapter      = 1,
  pages        = "1-27",
  year         = 2014,
  publisher    = "John Wiley~\& Sons",
}
@inbook{bitam2014bio2,
  title        = "Routing for Vehicular Ad~Hoc Networks",
  booktitle    = "Bio-inspired Routing Protocols for Vehicular Ad-Hoc Networks",
  author       = "Bitam, Salim and Mellouk, Abdelhamid",
  chapter      = 2,
  pages        = "29-48",
  year         = 2014,
  publisher    = "John Wiley~\& Sons",
}
@inbook{bitam2014bio3,
  title        = "Conventional Routing Protocols for {VANETs}",
  booktitle    = "Bio-inspired Routing Protocols for Vehicular Ad-Hoc Networks",
  author       = "Bitam, Salim and Mellouk, Abdelhamid",
  chapter      = 3,
  pages        = "49-78",
  year         = 2014,
  publisher    = "John Wiley~\& Sons",
}
@inbook{bitam2014bio4,
  title        = "Bio-inspired Routing Protocols for {VANETs}",
  booktitle    = "Bio-inspired Routing Protocols for Vehicular Ad-Hoc Networks",
  author       = "Bitam, Salim and Mellouk, Abdelhamid",
  chapter      = 4,
  pages        = "79-119",
  year         = 2014,
  publisher    = "John Wiley~\& Sons",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this is actually a `@incollection` http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1848216637.html seems to suggest to me that we are indeed talking about a monograph by the two authors here, so `@inbook` fits the bill perfectly. Your other points about `title` etc. are of course valid. I would argue, however, that there is little point in creating a separate `@inbook` entry for all chapters of a `@book` one cites: Just cite the book and give the page.

Comment: @moewe - You're right about the `@incollection` versus `@inbook` thing. (I think I was guided by my bibtex-related experience, where it it indeed necessary to use `@incollection`.) I'll change my answer accordingly.